# Шины от грузовиков

Tags: управление

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильнее: "Закупаем использованные шины ОТ грузовиков" или "Закупаем использованные шины грузовиков"?

Answer (score 2):

Это у вас реклама? Пишите ОТ. Думаю, это - меньшее из зол.
Потому как с точки зрения литературного русского языка - все плохо.
Шины не от грузовиков, а от колес. И не ОТ, а ДЛЯ.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Да не за что. Вы еще подождите, это стилистика, в таком вопросе лучше несколько мнений иметь.

Comment: Я, пожалуй, соглашусь.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрела в интернете, много объявлений типа "купим изношенные шины". Новые слова могут осложнить поиск вашей рекламы, если она на сайте.

Что касается "грузовых", то есть все варианты: "грузовые шины", "шины от грузовиков/грузовых автомобилей", "шины грузовиков", "шины для грузовиков". На мой взгляд, тут принципиальной разницы нет, лучше смотреть с позиции рекламщиков. Важна частота употребления в "поиске" (чтобы легче можно было найти ваше объявление).

Comment: "Шины для" - правильно, но в рекламе не стыкуется со "старые". Они уже не для а "от". Но само по себе "от" не совсем по-русски. Потому как они *от колес*